# Java - Contacts Manager Program

Tags: java

currently learning java in class and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this program. Most of the code is given by a project and really its only the main method we should be editing from what the assignment says but the part thats failing for me is one of the given classes. Below is the code and errors.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        myContactsManager myContactManager = new myContactsManager();

        Contact firstContact = new Contact("Russell", "random@gmail.com", "555-555-5555");
        addcontact(firstContact);
    }
}

class myContactsManager {
    Contact[] myfriends = new Contact[500];
    int friendsCount = 0;

    myContactsManager(){
        this.friendsCount = 0;
       this.myFriends = new Contact[500];
    }

    void addContact(Contact contact){
        myFriends[friendsCount] = contact;
        friendsCount++;
    }
    Contact searchContact(String searchName){
        for(int i=0; i<friendsCount; i++){
            if(myFriends[i].name.equals(searchName)) {
                return myFriends[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
class Contact {
    String name;
    String email;
    String phoneNumber;

    public Contact(String name, String email, String phoneNumber){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Error:(6, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method addcontact(Contact)
  location: class Main

Error:(16, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable myFriends

Error:(21, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable myFriends
  location: class myContactsManager

Error:(26, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable myFriends
  location: class myContactsManager

Error:(27, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable myFriends
  location: class myContactsManager

and the errors I am receiving.

Comment: `myContactManager.addcontact(firstContact);`

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. It seems like you have some mismatched references due to case (like **myfriends** or **addcontact**).

Answer (score 2):

Java is case sensitive. `myfriends` must be declared as `myFriends`. You're making the same mistake with the `addcontact` method, which should be `addContact`. It also needs to be called on an instance of the manager:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        myContactsManager myContactManager = new myContactsManager();

        Contact firstContact = new Contact("Russell", "random@gmail.com", "555-555-5555");
        myContactManager.addContact(firstContact);
    }
}

class myContactsManager {
    Contact[] myFriends = new Contact[500];
    //... the same as you already had
}
```

Comment: Thanks lol. Now I feel insanely stupid for not noticing that. I blame burn out. Just two weeks left of class then I'm done.